# Override .click() method of webElement in selenium using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to override the **.click()** method of selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement. Also I want that overrided click() method to be called implicitly whenever I perform click operation e.g,

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//some_xpath')
elem.click()
```

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the splinter framework, it puts a abstraction layer to selenium and basically already does what you want https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks. But I need this solution for selenium driver.

Comment: You can check the splinter source code to check how they are doing it and replicate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To override the click method :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command


# monkey patch the click method :

def WebElement_click(self):
    """Clicks the element."""
    print("my click")
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

WebElement.click = WebElement_click


# usage example :

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
driver.find_element_by_id("nav-questions").click()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank You :)

Answer (score 4):

I think actually overriding the `click()` method might prove tricky and result in unwanted behavior. You might be able to achieve what you're after though using the `EventFiringWebDriver`. See the following example,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.events import EventFiringWebDriver, AbstractEventListener

# My custom event listener
class MyListener(AbstractEventListener):

    def before_click(self, element, driver):
        print "Event : before element click()"

    def after_click(self, element, driver):
        print "Event : after element click()"


# Get an event-firing-web-driver instance
driver = EventFiringWebDriver(webdriver.Firefox(), MyListener())

# Visit a site
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/")

# Find an element
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

# Click on element
elem.click()

# Close browser
driver.close()
```

Script above outputs,

```
Event : before element click()
Event : after element click()
```

Comment: IMHO this is a more elegant solution. I wonder why there is less documentation on this topic (event listeners for selenium). Thanks for the useful explanation..